# Align decimal points to right in input type text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to format the numbers to two decimal places and also want to aligned the, i.e. don't want some numbers centered, some left aligned, etc.
I don't know how easy this is to do, but want to do alignment on the decimal point.Kind of like this:

```
 123.44
1465.23
  12.24
```

Right align is ok as long as all numbers have two dp. Don't want numbers to look like this:

```
1554
23.75
```

They should look like this:

```
1554.00
  23.75
```

HTML Code

```
 <table class="table grey-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="padding:1px 8px;">Description</th>
            <th style="padding:1px 8px;">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:1px 8px;">Countertops</td>
    <td style="width:150px;"><input type="text" id="txt_cm_countertops" readonly="true" style="width:150px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:1px 8px;">Li In.</td>
    <td style="width:150px;"><input type="text" id="txt_cm_countertops_lf" readonly="true" style="width:150px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:1px 8px;">Bowls</td>
    <td style="width:150px;"><input type="text" id="txt_cm_bowls" readonly="true" style="width:150px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:1px 8px;">Side Splashes</td>
    <td style="width:150px;"><input type="text" id="txt_cm_sidesplashes" readonly="true" style="width:150px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding:1px 8px;">Subtops</td>
    <td style="width:150px;"><input type="text" id="txt_cm_subtops" readonly="true" style="width:150px;"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<sript>
var I = 24; //These values are for demo. These are not hardcorded
var J = 15.5;
var K = 4;
var L = 4;
var M = 21.4;

$("#txt_cm_countertops").val(I);    
$("#txt_cm_countertops_lf").val(J); 
$("#txt_cm_bowls").val(K);  
$("#txt_cm_sidesplashes").val(L);   
$("#txt_cm_subtops").val(M);

</script>
```

This is the image of the above table Want to align the Total Column Having  [image]

Comment: That's not at all how the table looks -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/KzYAZ/, the last column seems to be inputs ?

Comment: Yes last column contains the input but i have set in css <input> border to none so it comes up with the above look. Well I also mentioned in the Title of the Post "input type text"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the css text-align: right attribute and JavaScript mask.

This jQuery plugin is one I've had good luck with:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Example:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Find a field with an ID of 'myNum' and mask it display a two digit number
  $("#myNum").mask("9.99");
  // Add mask of two digit number to anything with a class of 'twodigit'
  $(".twodigit").mask("9.99");
  // Really old browsers don't like the class method so you have to run a for/each
  // loop by class name
  $(".twodigit").each(function(){
     $(this).mask("9.99");
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I have checked the example and demo of the plugin but couldn't understand how to do :(

Comment: I've edited my code to give you three examples.  Hopefully this will help

Comment: Thanx! Let me check it.

Comment: I have done it `<input style="text-align:right;" id="myNum" value="232553" />` but it gives output `2.32` :( I want to mask it like 232553.00 Now what to do ? I tried `mask("99.99")` it gives output `23.25`. What will be the generalize `mask()` ?